# OCaml Strange Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, ocaml, binary-tree, ml

Okay, sorry guys, its me again x)
This function is supposed to replace a sub-tree of **dt** (which is a binary tree) at the coordinates specified by **coord** (like [0;1;0;0] where 0 means going left and 1 the opposite) by the sub tree **nt**.
By the way, the sub function returns the subtree with the specified coordinates.
I'm getting a syntax error

```
else if (List.hd coord)=0 then edit l coord nt
Error: Syntax error
#
```

i really dont know why :S
Thanks anyway :)

```
let rec edit dt coord nt =
        match dt with
              Decision(choiceL, costL, l, choiceR, costR, r) -> if (sub dt coord)=l then Decision(choiceL, costL, nt, choiceR, costR, r)
                                                                                                                            else if (sub dt coord)=r then  Decision(choiceL, costL, l, choiceR, costR, nt)
                                                                                                                            else if (List.hd coord)=0 then edit l coord nt
                                                                                                                            else edit r coord nt
            | Chance(eventL, probL, l, eventR, probR, r) ->   if (sub dt coord)=l then Chance(choiceL, costL, nt, choiceR, costR, r)
                                                                                                                            else if (sub dt coord)=r then let Chance(choiceL, costL, l, choiceR, costR, nt)
                                                                                                                            else if (List.hd coord)=0 then edit l coord nt
                                                                                                                            else edit r coord nt
            | Outcome value -> raise (Arg.Bad ("Bad argument")) 
    ;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you just need to get rid of the extra `let` in there.

Comment: thanks man, i also had choice and cost in the "chance" tab instead of prob and event x) i really need a sleep